# Return an existing razor view from middleware in asp.net core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my custom exception middleware, I want to get exceptions processed and return the same resource with a user friendly message.

E.g When `Account/Add` throws an `SqlException`, I return `Account/Add` response with a message which stored in `TempData` from exception middleware. I already 
got these view engine things done.

I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7238#issuecomment-357391426) extension method and usage for this purpose, with this, you can return all `IActionResult` implementations from middleware, great extension.
However, I could not find out how to return my conventional view that resides in my views folder such as `Views/Account/Add`

**Exception Middleware**

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

public ExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate next)
{
    _next = next;
}
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(context, ex);
    }
}

private void HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    //handle exception, log it and other stuff...
    //....

    var result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = context.Request.Path.ToString(),
    };
    //WithDanger is an extension method writes message to tempdata
    result.WithDanger("Error", exception.ToString());

    //Extension method
    context.WriteResultAsync(result);
}
```

This is what I tried but it is not working as I expected, it returns a blank page, it seems it does not make the razor view engine run to build my request page.

How can I make my middleware to return a `ViewResult` with my existing view properley?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of things missing. In order to return a view using a relative path, you need to trim off the leading slash:

```
ViewName = context.Request.Path.ToString().TrimStart('/')
```

You're also not awaiting the `WriteResultAsync` call. Change it to something like

```
private TaskHandleException(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    //handle exception, log it and other stuff...
    //....

    var result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = context.Request.Path.ToString().TrimStart('/'),
    };
    //WithDanger is an extension method writes message to tempdata
    result.WithDanger("Error", exception.ToString());

    //Extension method
    return context.WriteResultAsync(result);
}
```

And make sure you await the call to `HandleException`:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleException(context, ex);
    }
}
```

That should work :)

Comment: Thank you Kristian, it was my mistake, I 've forgatten to change signatures.:) However, right now, I got a routing error, Routing searches my view inside `Views/Home/Home/ThrowErr` instead `Views/Home/ThrowErr`. I had a test action `Home/ThrowErr`, simply throws error conditionally. (on first req throws error, on second returns view, for testing purposes).  I have default mvc routing only.  Should I use another path?

Comment: I tried adding a view in `Views/Account` called `Add.cshtml`. When I go to `/Account/Add` and throw an exception, I get the view served. I'm not sure what's causing it to look in `Views/Home/Home` ..

Comment: Note that I got this worked when I use `../Controller/Action` path convention for `ViewName`